# Understanding function in hotkeys.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a plugin similar to [hotkeys.js](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js#L198).

Now I was just going through the source and came across the following code:

```
jQuery.each(["keydown", "keyup", "keypress"], function() {
  jQuery.event.special[this] = {
    add: keyHandler
  };
});
```

after the each function I really fail to understand this part :

```
jQuery.event.special[this] = {
  add: keyHandler
};
```

What is that part doing? What is this kind of a construct called in JS? I am used to seeing nested Object literals in JS but not totally comfortable with them. Also I know that JS nowadays uses a lot of object literals to pass parameters.

Would somebody explain the above syntax and tell me what it is doing?

The exact line can also be found on [Github](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js#L198).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First

```
jQuery.each(["keydown", "keyup", "keypress"], function() {
```

iterates over array `["keydown", "keyup", "keypress"]`. Its handler is called 3 times (because 3 items in the array) and `this` in this function is `"keydown"`, `"keyup"` and `"keypress"` respectively.

So

```
jQuery.event.special[this] = {
  add: keyHandler
};
```

just adds Objects (`{ add: keyHandler }`) to `jQuery.event.special` Object with keys `"keydown"`, `"keyup"` and `"keypress"`.

So `jQuery.event.special` Object will look after that like this:

```
jQuery.event.special == {
  "keydown" : {...},
  "keyup" : {...},
  "keypress" : {...},
  ....
}
```

---

`someObject["childName"]` notation is the same as `someObject.childName`. But first allows you to read option name from some variable (`this` in your case) so `[]` is used.

`jQuery.event.special[this]` may be rewritten as `jQuery["event"]["special"][this]`

---

```
{
  add: keyHandler
}
```

`add` is a key. `keyHandler` is a function variable. In this case quotes for a key are omitted which is also right syntax. Same as:

```
{
  "add" : keyHandler
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur in depth answer , BTW , What is add and what is keyhandler ?